# Class, instance/object method

Tags: python, class, object

I am new to programming. I am very confused about this class/instance/ method definition.

I have a simple question.

If I draw a square with a red pen on a piece of paper, can somebody explain what is a class, method and object here?

Also, here is a code for a real program. Based on the above explanation, how can I start to think through Python similarly?

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
      window = turtle.Screen() #canvas to draw on
      window.bgcolor("red")

      brad = turtle.Turtle()
      brad.shape("triangle")
      brad.speed('10000')
      brad.forward(100)
      brad.right(90)
      brad.forward(100)
      brad.right(90)
      brad.forward(100)
      brad.right(90)
      brad.forward(100)




      window.exitonclick()


 draw_square()
```

Comment: Classes are a description of a thing (eg: the concept of a `Cat`). Objects are instances of classes (eg: `Freddie` the tabby cat). Methods are functions/actions (eg: `Freddie.meow()`)

Comment: that definitely helps! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your analogy, the class would be "Square", because it is an abstract concept representing the type of something (in this case, the type of thing you're drawing on the paper).  "Draw" would be the method, because it is the action being performed on the object.  The object would be the particular square you drew.  So if you drew two identical squares next to each other, you would have two objects, both having the same class.

I've commented your code to give an explanation to it:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():  # We are defining a method
      window = turtle.Screen() # window is an object.  Its class is turtle.Screen
      window.bgcolor("red") # We are calling the bgcolor() method, which sets the color

      brad = turtle.Turtle() # We are creating an object called brad, whose class is turtle.Turtle
      brad.shape("triangle") # We are calling a method on brad, called shape
      brad.speed('10000')    # We are calling a method on brad, called speed
      brad.forward(100)      # We are calling a method on brad, called forward
      brad.right(90)         # etc. etc.
      brad.forward(100)
      brad.right(90)
      brad.forward(100)
      brad.right(90)
      brad.forward(100)




      window.exitonclick()    # We are calling a method on window, called exitonclick


 draw_square()  # We are calling a method called draw_square, which we defined above
```